# Visual source safe headaches - Deleting files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I will pre-empt and say we are stuck using VSS here so changing it is not an option.

Anyway, one person, '`user a`' is deleting a file from their project. They then do a 'get latest' on the folder and it doesn't come back, so the user assumes they have truely deleted it from the project.

We have another user, '`user b`', who then looks at 'pending checkins', sourcesafe will then do a scan of all the files in '`user b`'s project. It then wants to 're-add' all of the files `user a` deleted.

This has caused a huge headache for the team. Any suggestions to stop this from happening again?

Comment: What type of project is it?  DB?  Web? Web App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a **Purge** in Visual Source Safe. This will remove the file for good.